# php loop through array with duplicate index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, duplicates

I am trying to loop through an array with duplicate indexes. But it only prints 3 times not all of them. I want to print all values in the array is that possible?

Here is my PHP code:

```
$data['Video'][0]['name']='a';
$data['Video'][1]['name']='b';
$data['Video'][1]['name']='c';
$data['Video'][3]['name']='d';
$data['Video'][3]['name']='e';

foreach ($data['Video'] as $video) {
    print_r($video);
}
```

And here is the output of that code:

```
Array
(
    [name] => a
)
Array
(
    [name] => c
)
Array
(
    [name] => e
)
```

Comment: You are changing the value of array index 3 and 1 two times. So in total there are only 3 arrays in $data['Video']

Comment: it will overwrite the value at that index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid duplicate entry of keys otherwise try this,

```
  $data['Video'][]['name']='a';
  $data['Video'][]['name']='b';
  $data['Video'][]['name']='c';
  $data['Video'][]['name']='d';
  $data['Video'][]['name']='e';

  foreach ($data['Video'] as $video) {
      print_r($video);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the duplicate indexes negate each other. So this is expected behavior. So when you set this in your code:

```
$data['Video'][0]['name']='a';
$data['Video'][1]['name']='b';
$data['Video'][1]['name']='c';
$data['Video'][3]['name']='d';
$data['Video'][3]['name']='e';
```

It really just means this:

```
$data['Video'][0]['name']='a';
$data['Video'][1]['name']='c';
$data['Video'][3]['name']='e';
```

The newer data assigned to the keys `1` and `3` overwrite what was previously there.

Comment: nice explainment +1 but they dont "negate" in mine opinion an better definition would be "overwrite" or "override"